# Duplicate instances of setInterval running from Service Worker after each app load

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a Service Worker that gets registered when my app starts and an init() function is called inside of there to kick off background processes, in particular, a `setInterval` which gets called every minute.  For testing purposes, I send out a notification to see it kick off at each interval.

The problem is, that whenever I reload the page, or open another tab with the same app, it continuously stacks a new `setInterval` instance, and I get a notification from each one of those.

For example, I open the app with a cleared cache, and I get one notification per minute.  Perfect.  I refresh that same page, and then I get two notification per minute (spread out by when I chose to click refresh). If I open a new tab with the same app, I get a third instance of `setInterval` starting at that moment, and should I refresh that tab too, I'd get another instance, etc, etc.

I feel embarrassed not finding an answer, but I've spent too much time reading and testing, but not getting anywhere.  How do I stop this behavior, and what's really going on here?

Is there a Service Worker event I can leverage that I can call `clearInterval` with when the tab is being refreshed or a new tab opened?

**UPDATE 2020-02-04**

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing.  Also, I leveraged the global space to set and clear the interval which takes care of individual tab reloading.  Half-way there!

```
function init() {
  // Clear the interval if it already exists on the global object
  if (self.globalObj.initInterval) self.clearInterval(self.globalObj.initInterval);
  // Set the interval to the global object
  self.globalObj.initInterval = self.setInterval(() => {
    // Notify the user every minute
    if (self.Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      self.registration.showNotification('You\'ve got new messages!', {
        body: 'Click this link to open a new browser window to view your messages.',
      });
    }
  }, 60000);
}

self.addEventListener('message', e => {
  if (e.data === 'init') init();
});
```

So there remains one more issue, and that's another browser tab.  Even though the code I just posted resolved multiple intervals running on reload, a new tab is still treated like a new thread.  But it's even more weird, because the timing of the next tab's notification, will always be stacked immediately after the first tab's notification fires, no matter when you start it.  So close.

I may need to fallback to a Shared Worker as was suggested, but we are trying to leverage Service Workers since we have a flow we leverage for everything else in there, and I'd like to find the solution within the Service Worker world.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker?

Comment: @Train I did, but it had very similar issues. :/

Comment: Did your answer resolve the issue? I'm not sure if this comment above was before or after you answered.

Comment: @Train My answer did resolve all the the issues, but earlier this week I looked at Shared Workers too as an alternative, but noticed similar behaviors.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through a lot of pain and trial, testing alternatives like Shared and Web Workers, I was able to pull off what I needed to staying with Service Workers.

So using the trimmed example I posted in my question, first here's the solution, and below that is the explanation.

```
self.globalObj = {};

function init(id) {
  // Clear the interval if it already exists on the global object
  if (self.globalObj.initInterval) self.clearInterval(self.globalObj.initInterval);
  // Set the interval to the global object
  self.globalObj.initInterval = self.setInterval(() => {
    // Notify the user every minute
    if (self.Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Click this link to open a new browser window to view your messages.',
        icon: './images/some-image.png',
      };
      if (id) notificationOptions.tag = id; // Every ID has to be unique; otherwise it won't trigger, but leaving that `tag` prop off, will always trigger a new notification
      self.registration.showNotification('You\'ve got new messages!', notificationOptions);
    }
  }, 60000);
}

self.addEventListener('message', e => {
  if (e.data === 'init') init(e.id);
});
```

**First half of the answer:**
If you set/clear from a global variable like in this example, you instantly resolve the browser reloading issue because it has a way to clear a previously stored one (I never thought an interval could perpetuate through a refresh, but it certainly does and you have to handle that like in this example!).

**Second half of the answer:**
While this simplistic dummy demo code doesn't expose the real use case of using a `fetch` call during the interval or dropping the interval and leveraging a `push` event instead, in either case, the cross-tab duplicating issue with notifications is resolved by using the `tag` property. So in a normal use case, whether a `fetch` with interval or a `push` is used, you need to pass in a unique `tag` string.  If there is no `tag` property, you'll get notifications on demand from all tabs, but if you provide a `tag` string value, only *one* notification will be pushed to the OS--ever.  So that means only one of the tabs will get their notification to actually post to the OS's notification system. Great!, no duplicates now. BUT, since it only ever allows one notification with a specific `tag` ever, your next `fetch` or `push` needs to return another unique `tag`/id, like a UUID, or possibly even the `body`'s value as the `tag`'s value as well if it's truly unique!

And there you have it!  No duplicated notifications on refresh, and no duplicated notifications across tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the init in the service worker code or your UI code?
Only 1 service worker instance is active no matter how many clients are open within the service worker's scope.

Another way you could do this is to create a new setInterval when each new client (tab) is opened via a message to the service worker. If that is the case you just need to create a guard in your service worker from creating multiple instances of the interval.

If the interval is created in the UI code then move it from the UI code to the service worker. No need to hog UI resources with a task like this anyway.

Comment: I just posted what I was doing that you can reference, including a fix for the individual tab reloading, but the second tab still has a residue issue.